# AT&T Galaxy SIII / Windows 7 64bit AMD/ Cannot mount USB drive

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb, samsung-kies, windows

I just want to transfer files between my new cell phone and my new computer.  I have been on the phone with both AT&T and Samsung tech support for two days. No joy. I and they have tried dozens of combinations of running Kies, Developer Debug Mode, pull the USB cord now, put it back in now... on and on. One guy had me yank the battery, "NOW!" I also called a magic phone number `*#7284#`, which is actually a backdoor into a settings menu. I have also tried following some suggestions here on android.stackexchange. All I want is for it to work like a USB memory stick. Plug it in, and there are my files in a Windows Explorer folder. Dream on,right?

The USB port on the PC worked for a Galaxy SII before the phone quit working completely. The cable is fine. But I tried other USB ports and other cables anyway.

Question 1. Can this be right? On a 64 bit Windows 7 OS? Is it supposed to be in system32?

[image: Is it supposed to be in system32?]

Question 2. Does the fact that the drivers without MTP in the name load okay indicate that the hardware on the phone is working?

Question 3. Anyone know of a backdoor that will allow me to mount at least the add-on SD card like a plain ol' external drive? I'll bet there is one.

Question 4. If all else fails, is there another (non-Samsung) Android phone with camera lenses on both sides that I might want to get instead?

UPDATE: I removed all SAMSUNG drivers from my PC. Reinstalled latest and greatest (1.5.6.0, which showed 1.5 million downloads). I did a factory reset on the phone. Rebooted everything. Tried again. No joy. I let Windows install drivers from the net. Still no joy.

Comment: Do you have WiFi available? This would offer some alternatives for easy data exchange.